Android , send mail through gmail SMTP from gmail account
I am trying to send mail from android /java using JavaMail (activation.jar + additionnal.jar + mail.jar). below is my code :
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Transport;


 protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Perform networking operations here

// initialize-----------
        fromEmail = "xxxx@gmail.com";
        fromPassword = "xxxxx";
        toEmailList .add( "yyyyy@gmail.com");
        emailSubject = "emailSubject";
        emailBody = "emailBody";

        emailProperties = System.getProperties();

        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth",true ); 
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com" ); 
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port",587 ); 
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable",true ); 
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.required",true ); 
         

        javax.mail.Session session = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(emailProperties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, fromPassword);
            }
        });



// Create message
        mailSession =  javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
        emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

        try {
            emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail, fromEmail));
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


        try {
            for (String toEmail : toEmailList) { 
                emailMessage.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,  new InternetAddress(toEmail));
                // emailMessage.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,  new InternetAddress(toEmail));
            }
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }



        try {
            emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
            emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");// for a html email
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      

        //----- Send Message ---------
     Transport transport = null;
        try {
            transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(emailHost, fromEmail, fromPassword);
            transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
          

        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }



        return null;
    }




I am getting error at.catch (MessagingException e)  with data:javax.mail.MessagingException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to smtp.gmail.com/173.194.76.108 (port 25) from /:: (port 55294): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)




It seems likely that your ISP is blocking that connection.  That may be your wireless provider or your local provider.  And this program is asking to be abused.  It's not that hard decompile this and get your credentials.  They will be used to send spam and your account will be locked.  You need to put most of this code into a server side component and call that with some sort of other authentication to the back end.

yes, I. know for the credential issue. But user will send mail from his mail credentials itself. into the app, user will write down his mail credentials, and teh app will use these data to send mail to another mail account. So, no more issue for password security. For the first topic that ISP. is. blocking that connection, Why ?. I have BlueMail into my android and it sends mails successfully using same account. what is the difference?

That makes sense.  Have you tried the other ports of 465 or 587?  I don't know how Bluemail works but port 25 is often blocked.

yes,  but did not work
